# Why does my C# Config file not load the settings after saving them?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to write my TextBox Text into a config file in C# WinForms to save the text. This is what I have done so far:

[The settings:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZskZa.png)

The code to save the settings:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.saveToTextBox = saveToTextBox.Text;
```

The code to load the settings:

```
saveToTextBox.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.saveToTextBox;
```

And the Events FormClosed and Load to save and load it.

But if I reopen my program the TextBox remains empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To persist the changes to `Settings` between application sessions, call the `Save` method:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

This should work both for .NET Framework 4 and for .NET 6/7.

Settings are saved in a file within a subfolder of the user's local hidden application data folder.

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot that one, thanks.